# Second match block not executing

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, ocaml

I was trying out some of the exercises in a dune build. I think my issue is due to the semicolons but I'm not really sure. When running the following code:

```
let somelist = [1;2;3;4] in
  (* last element in a list *)
    match (last somelist) with
    | Some (v) -> 
      print_endline "last value of list:" ;
      print_int v;
    | None -> () ;
    
    print_newline ();

    (* last 2 elements in a list *)
    match (last_two somelist) with
    | Some (a::b) ->
      print_endline "last 2 elements in list: \n";
      print_int a;
      print_int (List.hd b);
    | None -> () ;
    | Some ([]) -> () ;;

print_newline () ;;
```

it only prints out:

```
last value of list: 
4
```

instead of continuing and printing out the last 2 elements in the list afterwards. I tested out the other 2 functions, `last` and `last_two` in utop and they seem to work.

I wanted it to print out:

```
last value of list:
4
last 2 elements in list: 
3 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each branch of a `match` contains a list of expressions separated by `;` (or at least this is one way to describe the syntax). So your second `match` is contained within just one of the branches of the first `match`. I.e., it executes only if `last somelist` is `None`.

The usual way to solve this is by enclosing the first `match` in `begin / end` or parentheses. Here's one way to do this:

```
begin
match (last somelist) with
| Some (v) -> 
  print_endline "last value of list:" ;
  print_int v;
| None -> ()
end;

print_newline ();

match (last_two somelist) with
.  .  .
```